# Calculating the century from a given year

Tags: python, return

There was a condition which I had to use return instead of print because if I used print the if condition won't continue(correct me if I'm wrong), now I need to see the result(in some sites such as code fight how they make things together to check if the solution is right)

```
def centuryFromYear(year):
    """Calculates the century for a given year: 
    Example: year 1 = 1, year 100 = 1, year 101 = 2 year 1954 = 19 etc."""
    if len(str(year)) == 1 or 2:
        return 1
    if len(str(year)) == 3:
        if year[1:3] == 0:
            return year[0]
    else:
        return year[0] + 1
    if len(str(year)) == 4:
        if year[1:4] == 0:
           return year[0] + 0
    else:
        return year[0:2] + 1
```

Comment: What is the problem? i.e. what is the expected output and what are you seeing now?

Comment: `print(centuryFromYear(2018))`?

Comment: Your identation is off. What should `if year[1:3] == 0` accomplish...when ever is a list with len > 0 ==  0 ? Your `ifs` are lacking elses so they return "something" in case the if does not match - in this cases he method will return `None` implicitly.

Comment: @sam Given a year, return the century it is in. The first century spans from the year 1 up to and including the year 100, the second - from the year 101 up to and including the year 200, etc.

Comment: `if len(str(year)) == 1 or 2:` doesn't do what you think it does.  This evaluates to the same as `if (len(str(year)) == 1) or 2`

Comment: @iman_sh77 Okay, but that doesn't tell us what the problem is that you're trying to solve. And there are so many problems with this code, it's really hard to tell which one you're asking about.

Comment: @rdowell so how can I fix it?

Comment: @Aran-Fey I'm trying to find out for ex: 1905 is which century 200 is second century and 2000 is 20 century but 2001 is 21century and etc.tnx all for responding <3

Comment: So the problem is that the function doesn't work correctly? What's all this about seeing the return values, then?

Comment: You cannot make a conditional compare against multiple values at the same time like that.  Saying `if x == y or z` doesn't evaluate to `if (x == y) or (x == z)`  Look up operator precedence to understand why this is, and you'll also see why your function always returns 1.

Comment: the problem is that it doesn't show me any result except 1 i want the correct if condition return the result therefor I can see the result not show empty thing in console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really a logical problem, its more a math problem - dont convert your int into a string - instead calculate the century:

```
def centFromYear(year):
    return (year-1)//100 +1   # substract 1 so 100 is 1 as well, floordiv by 100, add 1

for n in range(1,2000,100): # testcase centuries
    for m in range(-1,2):    # testcase -1,0,+1 to the centuries
        print(n+m, centFromYear(n+m))
```

Output:

```
inputyear / calculated century
(0, 0)
(1, 1)
(2, 1)
(100, 1)
(101, 2)
(102, 2)
(200, 2)
(201, 3)
...
(1900, 19)
(1901, 20)
(1902, 20)
```

Comment: okay I accept math part but again in the consol I aint see any result                                                     def centuryFromYear(year):
    return (year - 1) // 100 + 1
centuryFromYear(19)

Comment: @iman_sh77  The function `centFromYear(1987)` returns an integer number. To show in in the console, print it:   `print(centFromYear(1987))` - to use it for calculation, store it in a variable:  `century = centFromYear(2018)` - and use the variable